# How to create a new terminal and run a command in it?

Tags: c++

I have a function like this

```
void smbProcess(){
    string smbTargetIP;
    cout<<"Target IP:  ";
    cin>>smbTargetIP;
    string commandSmb_S = "crackmapexec smb " + smbTargetIP;
    int smbLength = commandSmb_S.length();
    char commandSmb_C[smbLength + 1];
    strcpy(commandSmb_C, commandSmb_S.c_str());
    system("xterm -hold -e commandSmb_C");
}
```

I want to create a new terminal and run my command (like this *"crackmapexec smb 192.168.1.0/24"*). But it doesn't work. When I try this, it works

```
system("xterm -hold -e date");
```

These are also doesn't work

```
system("xterm -hold -e 'commandSmb_C'");
system("xterm -hold -e "commandSmb_C"");
```

If you know another way to do this it will works too

Comment: Construct a string for the command using + operators, whatever, and pass that to the `system()` call using the `c_str()` function. I am pretty sure I've seen that question asked a billion times here, and answered.

Comment: Well, if you found a solution based on my comment, which is working for you,  feel free to post that as an elaborate [answer] yourself. This should help users researching at the same problem in future.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "xterm -hold -e" to commandSmb_S

```
void smbProcess(){
    string smbTargetIP;
    cout<<"Target IP:  ";
    cin>>smbTargetIP;
    string commandSmb_S = "xterm -hold -e crackmapexec smb " + smbTargetIP;
    int smbLength = commandSmb_S.length();
    char commandSmb_C[smbLength + 1];
    strcpy(commandSmb_C, commandSmb_S.c_str());
    system(commandSmb_C);
}
```